# how to use phpdoc webinterface?

Tags: php, phpdoc

i have phpdoc through mamp. and i followed their tutorial, typed this in the Terminal.

```
 pear config-set data_dir /path/to/document_root/pear
```

of course i changed the /path/to/document_root to my web space folder.

but then what? how can i access phpdoc through webinterface?

Comment: I feel your pain. The documentation is dense and unclear to neophytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never installed phpdocumentor on mamp but I did on wamp. What you need to do is install pear on your mamp. When you did you can just copy the phpdoc web folder to your web root and go to it by visiting it in the browser.

For a bit more information on installing take a look here:
[Resource 1](http://www.armetiz.info/installation-phpdocumentor-avec-wamp/)
[Resource 2](http://www.webeks.net/computer/other/wamp-pear-installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have pear's data_dir set as you show above, and your Apache server is running, you should be able to reach the phpDocumentor web interface at http://localhost/pear/PhpDocumentor/index.html